# Create a Html row on select change with input (Number of row are dependent on select value selected)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a html table rows on select change my idea to create row is based on the select changes the number of select option is selected that many number or rows i want to be created in a specific html table with a input text box but that is applicable on button click i have no idea how to create on select change

HTML:

```
<select id="Number_of_position"  onchange="getval(this);"></select> 
<table id="Positions_names"></table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var select = document.getElementById("Number_of_position"); 
    for (var i = 100; i >= 1; i--) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i; 
        select.add(option, 0);
    }

});

function getval(sel) {
    alert(sel.value);
}

$("#addRow").click(function () {
    $("#Positions_names").append("<tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: I can't understand what you want to achieve: you want to create a number of row and that number is the number you select on the select node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you remove `onchange` attribute and switch to the [**unobtrusive**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) way of binding event handlers

`<select id="Number_of_position"`<s>`onchange="getval(this);"`</s>`></select>`

You're looking for jQuery's [**`change(handler)`**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler.

This will update the `table` with fresh content each time you change `select` value:

```
var select = $("#Number_of_position"), table = $("#Positions_names");

select.change(function () {
    var rows = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) {
        rows += "<tr><td><input type='text'></td></tr>";
    }
    table.html(rows);
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2ksyy7L/)

Comment: ᴀʀᴛᴜʀ ғɪʟɪᴘɪᴀᴋ i have a quick question why my option are starting from 100 to 0ne they should start from 1 to 100

Comment: @Shaik , because your `for` loop is reversed. You have to use this: `for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)`  instead of this: `for (var i = 100; i >= 1; i--)`  [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2ksyy7L/1/)